# Headphone issues

Tags: headphones

Whenever I plug my headphones into my LG Ultimate 2 it triggers a variety of issues including: Randomly turning volume up and down, ramdomly start playing music, pausing videos ect.

I spent alot of money on these headphones and I can't afford another decent pair, please help me find a fix for this.

Comment: Is this just right when you plug it in, or the whole time afterward?  Are you inserting the plug all the way?

Comment: Bad headphones, or bad headphone jack. Hate to bring it to ya.

Comment: We do not know what *etc.* contains so consider mentioning every action. The category of events you mentioned are actually features in some apps or ROMs. Volume up/down is probably happening because system or an app stores your media level preference for speakers and earphones. Randomly start playing music is also a feature of many music player app. They assume that if earphones are plugged, you must be going to listen something.

Comment: Pausing videos is also a feature of media player apps because a developer may have assumed that you would be watching private videos at some time and accidental removal of earphones *could be quite embarrassing*.  Begin with editing your question to list the Android version, the name of apps which starts playing music and pauses a video. // On a second thought, this may be a technical glitch.